# Need mobile skin for mobile screenshots

Tags: android, screenshot

I have a few mobile screenshots, I want to put different kinds of mobile skins around them. Could anyone give some pointers where I can upload the screenshots and select mobile skins for them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wrap your app screenshots in real device artwork, there is a [**Device Art Generator**](http://developer.android.com/distribute/promote/device-art.html) in the Android developer page

This [**Android Asset Studio**](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html) page have a device generator for selected devices